# Как поменять цвет в теге select а именно в выпадающем списке options?

Tags: jquery, css, form, select

```
    <option value="12">Черный</option>
    <option value="11">Коричневый</option>
```

Нужно чтобы выпадающий список был черного цвета а текст белый

Answer (score 1):

Ну если только цвет и фон (ещё размер текста) то можно - просто задайте стили для `select option`

```css
select option {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Другие стили не получится. К option не применяются. Если нужно всякие отступы и ещё что-то - то только плагин